# Get Specific Range of List Items (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I have this block of code I'm working with :

```
// get the collection of librarys from the injected repository
librarySearchResults = _librarySearchRepository.GetLibraries(searchTerm);

// map the collection into a collection of LibrarySearchResultsViewModel view models
libraryModel.LibrarySearchResults =
    librarySearchResults.Select(
        library =>
        new LibrarySearchResultsViewModel
        {
            Name = library.Name,
            Consortium = library.Consortium,
            Distance = library.Distance,
            NavigateUrl = _librarySearchRepository.GetUrlFromBranchId(library.BranchID),
            BranchID = library.BranchID
        }).ToList();
```

All this does is take the results of `GetLibraries(searchTerm)`, which returns a list of `LibrarySearchResult` objects, and maps them over to a list of `LibrarySearchResultsViewModel`'s.

While this works well for small result sets, once I get up into the 1,000's, it really starts to drag, taking about 12 seconds before it finishes the conversion.

**My question :**

Since I'm using paging here, I really only need to display a fraction of the data that's being returned in a large result set. Is there a way to utilize something like `Take()` or `GetRange()`, so that the conversion only happens for the records I need to display? Say out of 1,000 records, I only want to get records 20 through 40, and convert them over to the view models.

I'm all for any suggestions on improving or refactoring this code as well.

Comment: Please see the FAQ regarding signatures.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior  Specifically `Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.

Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.`

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.  I'd recommend you read the FAQ in it's entirety to make sure you follow the community guidelines.  I also recommend this post on meta for more information.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `Skip` and `Take`:

```
// take records from 20 to 40
var records = librarySearchResults.Skip(20).Take(20);
```

You can easily paginate it (you'll need `page` and `pageSize`).

On the other hand you're using `ToList` there, consider using *just* `IEnumerable`, conversion to list can eat up lots of time, especially for large data set.

Answer (score 7):

you can use `Skip()` and `Take()` together to enable paging.

```
var idx = // set this based on which page you're currently generating
librarySearchResults.Skip(idx * numitems).Take(numitems).Select(lib => ...);
```

Comment: Walkhard was a minute sooner, but this works great as well. +1